# Dynamically setting empty views : is it safe?

Tags: android, listview

We have four ListViews in a FrameLayout in one of our activities. We
also have a common WebView in this Framelayout set as EmptyView for
each of these lists.
The content of this TextView is supposed to change at runtime
depending on different contexts.

As a result, we call:
1. mEmptyView.loadData(...) followed by
2. mListOne.setEmptyView(mEmptyView) calls.

This works fine most of the times. But sometimes we are getting,
IllegalStateException.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131362332, class
android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class my.own.activity.MainAct
$UIAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1492)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
at android.widget.AdapterView.updateEmptyStatus(AdapterView.java:724)
at android.widget.AdapterView.setEmptyView(AdapterView.java:637)
```

Question: Is it safe to change content of an empty view and call
ListView#setEmptyView at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Just one idea... Have you tried using ViewGroup and its addView method? RelativeLayout is a viewgroup